# Ошибки при merge в Unity2D

Tags: unity3d, git, github

С другом решили вместе делать проект в Unity2D. Подключили git и сделали репозиторий в github.
Сижу, проверяю работу с ветками, создал две, для первой ветки в проекте в скрипте написал комментарий, а для второй просто передвинул объект на сцене.
В итоге, при попытке merge двух этих веток вылетает ошибка связанная с layout, не могу понять как решить проблему, ведь layout у меня один, а каждая ветка считает его другим. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить.
Gitignore, если что, использую отсюда https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот текст ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так посмотрите в редакторе, что поменялось то там (Open in editor). Может понятнее станет.

Comment: там просто id меняются

Comment: Ну, если всё остальное не менялось, просто выберите там, что решить конфликт, используя код той ветки, которая по вашему более актуальная.

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось эти файлы просто были созданы до gitignore и поэтому не игнорировались, я обновил индекс гита и удалил эти файлы из github'а, теперь все работает